# Hostname in Create Route of OpenShift v3 not availale

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I want to use custom domain (my domain) for Openshift 3 host. But when I go to Applications => Routes => Create Route. In this screen, the field Hostname just alway disable, so that I can't input my custom domain here.

How to enable this field to add my domain?

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3dxG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OpenShift environment are you using? Also, what do you mean by disabled? That screenshot looks normal, you need to click in the field to add the hostname. Are you saying clicking in the field doesn't work?

BTW, if you are on OpenShift Online Starter, then you don't have the ability to use custom domain names. You would have to use the Pro tier if wanting to host a permanent site with custom domain name. The Starter environment is only intending for testing and development.

For details of differences between OpenShift Online Starter and Pro see:

- https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm using Starter